# Need help putting a minimization equation into scipy weighted least squares solver

Tags: python, scipy, regression, linear-algebra

My question is how can I put a weighted least squares problem into a python solver.  I'm trying to implement the approaches in the paper found [here](https://vision.in.tum.de/_media/spezial/bib/ssvm_ps.pdf) (PDF warning).  There is an overview of the problem at the bottom of the post.

Specifically I want to start with the following minimization equation (19 in the paper):

[latex formula can be found here](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7Bmin%7D%7B%5CTheta%20%5Cepsilon%20M%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bm%7D(w(i%2Cj))%5Cleft%20%7C%20%5CPsi(i%2Cj)*%5CTheta%20(i%2Cj)%20-%20I(i%2Cj)%20%5Cright%20%7C%5E%7B2%7D):

```
\frac{min}{\Theta \epsilon M} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{m}(w(i,j))\left | \Psi(i,j)*\Theta (i,j) - I(i,j) \right |^{2}
```

It is represented as a weighted least squares problem.
`w`, `psi`, and `I` are my knowns, and I am trying to solve for `theta`.

I tried at first creating a function that takes a theta and returns the sum of this equation exactly as it's expressed above.  Then I passed it to scipy.optimize.least_squares, but the theta values always remained the same after optimization.  I tried implementing a jacobian, but the resulting sum explodes to huge negative values.  It also takes ages as I'm attempting to run this on images (I is the pixel value for a pixel j with light i).

I then realized I'm almost certainly misunderstanding how to solve this problem and could use some help approaching it.  My current code is below:

```
def theta_solver(self, theta):
    imshape = self.images.shape
    sm = 0

    for j in j_array:
        for i in i_array:
            w = self.get_w(i, j, theta)
            psi = self.non_diff_smoothing(self.get_psi(i, j))
            diff = psi*(theta[i, j]) - self.I[i, j]
            res = w*(diff)
            sm += res

    return sm

def solve_theta(self, theta_guess):
    res = scipy.optimize.least_squares(self.theta_solver, theta_guess)
```

Something tells me I'm way off base for how I'm approaching this problem, and I could use a finger in the right direction.  Thanks for your time.

Problem overview:

This particular vision approach is called photometric stereo.  By taking several images of a scene with different light sources, we can create a 3D reconstruction of that scene.
One issue is the `1/r^2` decay in lighting is dependent on distance from the light source, which means this can't be solved by normal linear solutions.
The approach documented in the paper is a nonlinear approach for solving near light photometric stereo.  It does two things:

- it solves the surface `Z`, and
- the albedos/intensities at each pixel represented by theta, by alternating the solvers.

In this question I'm only trying to solve the `theta` element of the equation, which can be solved via weighted least squares.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was heavily overthinking the problem.  This can be decomposed to a simple linear solution of the form Ax = b.  When looking at an error equation, in this case:

```
argmin(THETA) sum(W * ||PSI * THETA - I||^2)
```

we can just distribute the weight through the parts within the root mean square.  Our equation ends up being:

```
W * PSI * THETA = W * I
```

Which we can solve using your favorite linear solver (i.e. conjugate gradient descent)